# How to convert json to a list in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have some code that is converting some JSON from an API call into a Python list like this:

```
import json as js
def flatten(listText):
    def _flatten(item):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for value in item.values():
                yield from _flatten(value)
        else:
            yield item

    return [list(_flatten(d)) for d in listText]

jsonText = '[{"stationID":"ABCD123","obsTimeUtc":"ABCD123-ABCD123-ABCD123:ABCD123:ABCD123","obsTimeLocal":"ABCD123-ABCD123-ABCD123 ABCD123:ABCD123:ABCD123","neighborhood":"ABCD123","softwareType":"EasyWeatherV1.4.6","country":"AU","solarRadiation":0,"lon":0,"realtimeFrequency":null,"epoch":0,"lat":0,"uv":0,"winddir":0,"humidity":0,"qcStatus":0,"imperial":{"temp":0,"heatIndex":0,"dewpt":0,"windChill":0,"windSpeed":0,"windGust":0,"pressure":0,"precipRate":0,"precipTotal":0,"elev":0}}]'
listText = js.loads(jsonText)
print(flatten(listText))
```

This works perfectly however the JSON has changed so the string is now wrapped in {"observations:} like this:

```
{"observations":[{"stationID":"ABCD123","obsTimeUtc":"ABCD123-ABCD123-ABCD123:ABCD123:ABCD123","obsTimeLocal":"ABCD123-ABCD123-ABCD123 ABCD123:ABCD123:ABCD123","neighborhood":"ABCD123","softwareType":"EasyWeatherV1.4.6","country":"AU","solarRadiation":0,"lon":0,"realtimeFrequency":null,"epoch":0,"lat":0,"uv":0,"winddir":0,"humidity":0,"qcStatus":0,"imperial":{"temp":0,"heatIndex":0,"dewpt":0,"windChill":0,"windSpeed":0,"windGust":0,"pressure":0,"precipRate":0,"precipTotal":0,"elev":0}}]}
```

and because of this, instead of returning a list like this:

```
[['ABCD123', 'ABCD123:ABCD123:ABCD123', 'ABCD123-ABCD123-ABCD123 ABCD123:ABCD123:ABCD123', 'ABCD123', 'EasyWeatherV1.4.6', 'AU', 0, 0, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

It just returns:

```
[['observations']]
```

How can I change the code so that it works with the new Json format?

Comment: `print(flatten(listText["observations"]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is pick the value corresponding to the `observations` field like so:

```
listText = js.loads(jsonText)['observations']
```

This gives the output that you require